# Which directory is the .properties file located for OOTB ATG Handlers (i.e. ProfileFormHandler)?

Tags: java, atg

I'm working to debug a custom FormHandler that extends ATG's out of the box ProfileFormHandler and want to know if any of the methods (as well as which ones) were overridden by the custom java code. I'm having no success with finding where the .properties file lies in correlation with the ProfileFormHandler.java file.

The custom FormHandler is named "MYKProfileFormHandler.java" and is located at the filepath myk/userprofiling/MYKProfileFormHandler.java

Comment: They are in jar files in each of the modules.  You need to explode the jar files to get at the config (or get a tool that allow you to view the contents of jar files).

Comment: If you have a file that overrides an OOTB file the only way your application would be able to pick it up is if you have a property file that references the extended class instead of the original one, so search your source code for references to the MYKProfileFormHandler. As far as finding out which methods are overridden, the properties file won't help you, you should look at the java code for this. In 'Eclipse' you can use ctrl+o+o and it will show you which methods exist in the current file and which in the parents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the server comes up, use the dyn/admin to find where the properties file is located. Use the following URL with your hostname and port 
http://host:port/dyn/admin/nucleus/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler/?propertyName=serviceConfiguration

On this page, you'll find the properties configuration at different module layers. You'll find the properties setup in your application towards the bottom. It will look something like this:

/u02/oracle/domains/servername/Domain/servers/instancename/tmp/_WL_user/Estore/qwo6y/war/WEB-INF/ATG-INF/DCS/config/config.jar/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler.properties

This is the temporary location where your application server (in this case weblogic) would extract it for its use. But this helps you to find which module has this jar. In the above example, DCS is the module.

Like bated had mentioned, you'll see that in the config.jar inside your built EAR.

Also, I am assuming that you've the source code. Just search for ProfileFormHanlder and you can find it. Please note that even though your custom formhandler is MYKProfileFormHandler, the component is still ProfileFormHandler.

Comment: Didn't the OP ask for a way to find out where the properties file is? Here you give him the path to the component instead of a way to find it. Surely that doesn't answer his question?

Answer (score 0):

To view all configuration applied to any component (e.g. a form handler) open up dyn/admin and locate the component you are searching for (http://localhost:8080/dyn/admin/nucleus/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFormHandler/) then select 'View Service Configuration'.

This will provide the path to where the config exists and the order in which the config is applied to your component.